# jQuery - Why is theappended Div always on top?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a div as background picture. The div is added through jquery. Although it has a z-index of zero it is always on top. How can I put in the back?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N84Js/3/)

JS

```
$('#wrap').append(      


    $('<div />').addClass("box")


);
```

CSS

```
.box{
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
background: green;
opacity: 0.7;
position: absolute;
top:0;
z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the z-index of your content as well

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    .... /* the rest of the css */
}
```

That will solve the problem as well.

Amit Soni's comment (as well as all new answers) should work as well, but setting a negative z-index might give problems with possible backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

change you z-index as follows:

```
.box{
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
background: green;
opacity: 0.7;
position: absolute;
top:0;
z-index:-1000;
}
```

code here : http://jsfiddle.net/N84Js/4/

because by default both divs are set to z-index 0

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioned divs have a higher precedence than relative divs, have you tried giving it a negative z-index?

Comment: shouldn't it be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

by default the two divs are having z-index = 0. so try to give negative z-index for the div which you want to display at background. see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N84Js/7/)

```
.box{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```